# Does it make sense to test delegate methods in model spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usually, these delegate method(s) is tested in their own class. Does it still make sense to test them again in the class where the delegation is made?

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :username, :email, :name,
           to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

My question is do I still need to test `@post.user_name` again inside `post_spec.rb`?

Comment: What's your objective for testing these methods?

Comment: make sure all these methods are available for `Post` model

Comment: you never "need" to test anything. it's always about tradeoffs! what you should test is the "public" api of your class. if those delegates are part of it, they should be tested in one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests are usually written to test correctness of your implementation. In this case, these methods are implemented through ActiveRecord, so testing them would be tantamount to testing AR.

On the other hand, some of your other code will fail if these methods are removed from your object, so you want to make sure that these interactions are covered at the controller / feature / integration layer.